# calculate percentages of scientific e notations equations in python (beginner level)

Tags: python, assignment-operator, notation

**The current volume of a water reservoir (in cubic metres)**

```
reservoir_volume = 4.445e8
```

**The amount of rainfall from a storm (in cubic metres)**

```
rainfall = 5e6
```

---

Below is a question asked for assigning and modifying arithmetic operators in python:

**increase reservoir_volume by 5% to account for stormwater that flows into the reservoir in the days following the storm**

```
reservoir_volume *= 1.05
```

**decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation**

```
reservoir_volume *= 0.95
```

**subtract 2.5e5 cubic metres from reservoir_volume to account for water that's piped to arid regions.**

```
reservoir_volume -= 2.5e5
```

---

Just a newbie in python, with no qualifications in maths. I more or less completely understand functions of the compound operator questions asked and can infer the answers from above.

But what about the below question:

**decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff**

```
rainfall *= .9
```

---

I can't seem to work it out.  How is '.9' 10% of 5000000? Am I completely missing something here? Am I using the multiplication pf compound operator incorrectly?

Comment: A number reduced by 10% is 90% of the original number.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it really doesn't seem to be about programming, but rather about the foundation of percentage calculations. wile there is some superficial relation to python, the idiosyncracies of the language seem to be well understood by the poster, leaving only the problem of the percentage calculation.

Comment: `decrease the rainfall variable by 10% to account for runoff` sounds very similar to `decrease reservoir_volume by 5% to account for evaporation` which you said you understood.

Comment: @umlaute go for it mate

Comment: @BlivetWidget thanks.